# How does shortcut link generated?

Tags: links

I notice there a shortcut icon in my desktop. I wonder how does this shortcut generated? I must be accidentally press something.

[image]

P/S : I using Linux

Comment: There are few desktop environments available. If you can create a shortcut on your desktop, so can any program you run. Maybe your browser did it; or some extension upon some keystroke. Keystrokes are usually customizable. Even if you provide details (desktop enviroment, browser etc.), there will be no way for us to tell what *you did*; so it's not the question needs details. The point is we can only guess. I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based. (For comparison: "how can I create a shortcut?" is a *different* question. This one is answerable if there are enough details provided.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concur with Kamil, either the website you visited created the shortcut or you dragged, used a key-combo or other various methods to generate shortcuts.  If this issue continues you may be able to deduce the cause.

1: delete that shortcut, return to the website and see if it reappears.

2: if you get more shortcuts, when they appear think back to what you did, and I suspect you would then find what process they are being created.

Comment: You are not posting and answer here. You are posting a comment. By endlessly posting comments like answers here you run the risk of being limited in your access here or outright banned. Please slow down and learn about how this community works [when it comes to answers over here](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).